# Microsoft Report Builder with Postgresql and multiple CTEs

Tags: postgresql, reporting-services, common-table-expression

I have a problem creating DataSets with CTE in the current Microsoft Report Designer.

My DataSource is a PostgreSQL Database and I use the current Version of PGNP to connect to.

The connection works fine, I can create DataSets based on Queries and get my data.

BUT if I try to create more complex queries, like for example with multiple CTE, I won't get any fields.

Exampe:

```
SELECT 'Test' as test
```

Will return one column (test) with one row (Test)

```
WITH Test as (SELECT 'Test' as test)
SELECT Test
       , 'Success' as result
FROM   Test
```

Will return two columns (test, result) with one row (Test, Success)

Till now, everything is ok.

But if I want to use more then one CTE, I have to face the following problems:

```
WITH Test as (SELECT 'Test' as test),
     TestB as (SELECT 'Test B' as test)
SELECT ta.test, tb.test, 'Success' as result
FROM   Test ta, TestB tb
```

Will fail with the following error message:
"Undefined table Test"

```
;WITH Test as (SELECT 'Test' as test),
      TestB as (SELECT 'Test B' as test)
SELECT ta.test, tb.test, 'Success' as result
FROM   Test ta, TestB tb
```

Will return no columns and no rows.

Any idea why this happens?

**Edit A:**
Here a (shorternd) Version of my actual query:

```
WITH calls AS (
SELECT  acv.id
        , acv.created
        , acv.state
        , acv.statistics_category
        , acv.duration
        , aqv.id as queue_id
        , aqv.name as queue_name
        , acv.target
        , acv.target_name
        , acv.queue_time
        , acv.ringing_duration
        , acv.hold_time
FROM        acd_call_view acv
LEFT JOIN   acd_queue_view aqv ON (aqv.id = acv.fk_acdqueue_id)
ORDER BY    acv.id, acv.created
),
calls_answered as (
    SELECT  *
    FROM    calls
    WHERE   statistics_category = 'answered'
)
SELECT * FROM calls_answered
```

Result: "Unknown table calls"

**Edit B:**
Sorry, had two leftovers from the shortening remaining in the query

**Edit C:**
Tested Query in pgAdmin III: Working

Tested Query in JasperSoft Studio: Working

Tested Query in MS Report Builder with PGNP: "Undefined table calls"

**Edit D:**
As soon as I remove the second CTE, I get results

```
WITH calls AS (
SELECT  acv.id
        , acv.created
        , acv.state
        , acv.statistics_category
        , acv.duration
        , aqv.id as queue_id
        , aqv.name as queue_name
        , acv.target
        , acv.target_name
        , acv.queue_time
        , acv.ringing_duration
        , acv.hold_time
FROM        acd_call_view acv
LEFT JOIN   acd_queue_view aqv ON (aqv.id = acv.fk_acdqueue_id)
ORDER BY    acv.id, acv.created
)
SELECT * FROM calls
```

Works fine, so I get results, the PGNP Ole DB Driver seems to work fine, the connection is up, everything is okay.

As soon, as I add the second CTE, I get the error

Comment: Works here.  (please post your exact query) BTW: the leading semicolon `;` will introduce an empty statement (NULL statement) in postgresql.

Comment: Hi, this is the exact query ... well I tested it with exactly this query and it doesn't work here

Comment: Ah okay, this explains, why the CTE with the leading ; won't return any results.
But why do I get the "undefined table Test" error if I try to work with more than one CTE

Comment: Maybe your framework quoted the identifiers? /crystal-ball

Comment: `date(created) = date(now())` are supposed to be casts? ( try `created::date` ,or the ANSI version: `CAST (created AS date)`

Comment: I removed the WHERE Statement, still get "Undefined table calls"

Comment: But since the same error occures with my "Test" Query, I think the problem does not lie within my query but within the way I use multiple CTEs

Comment: `apv.id` There is no correlation nampe `apv` in your last query. Please post the *real* query (or at least test it before you post it here) And the problem is *not* in the CTE's.

Comment: Sorry, forgot this two columns. They refered to a left join I removed for shortening purpose.
Query is corrected and tested in JasperSoft Report Studio - Working ... in MS Report Builder still "unknown table calls"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, here the solution:

Seems like the PGNP OleDB Driver cannot handle multiple CTEs.

Installed the ODBC Driver and configured a new DateSource via ODBC.

Now I get my results and am happy :-)

Nevertherless, thank you joop for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Works here (just plain psql terminal) , so the error must be in your framework/client application:

```
CREATE TABLE acd_call_view    
        ( id INTEGER NOT NULL
        , created timestamp
        , state integer
        , statistics_category  text
        , duration INTEGER
        , target INTEGER
        , target_name INTEGER
        , queue_time INTEGER
        , ringing_duration INTEGER
        , hold_time INTEGER
        , fk_acdqueue_id INTEGER
        );
CREATE TABLE acd_queue_view    
        ( id INTEGER NOT NULL
        , name  text
        );


WITH calls AS (
SELECT  acv.id
        , acv.created
        , acv.state
        , acv.statistics_category
        , acv.duration
        , aqv.id as queue_id
        , aqv.name as queue_name
        , acv.target
        , acv.target_name
        , acv.queue_time
        , acv.ringing_duration
        , acv.hold_time
FROM        acd_call_view acv
LEFT JOIN   acd_queue_view aqv ON aqv.id = acv.fk_acdqueue_id
ORDER BY    acv.id, acv.created
        )
, calls_answered as (
    SELECT  *
    FROM    calls
    WHERE   statistics_category = 'answered'
)
SELECT * FROM calls_answered
        ;
```

Comment: Yep, the queries are working - I use them for reports with Jasper Reporting Server and everything is okay.

But I need to move the reports to Microsoft SSRS. So I got the PGNP Ole DB connector, to provide SSRS a connection to my PostgreSQL Datesource and tried to move the queries to the Report Builder.

As I said, the queries are working (in pgAdmin III and in Jasper Studio) but not with MS Report Builder via Ole DB PGNP.

I think, there are problems with PGNP and multiple CTEs, but I cannot find anything about it ...

So I thought maybe someone here had the same trouble :)

Comment: You are right, seems to be a driver problem ... Via ODBC everything works fine, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I contacted PGNP support, and they responded quickly that the bugs in the CTEs handling were fixed in build 1.4.0.3425.